# Background CSS issue - not repeating

Tags: css, html

I got a quick question and hope the answer is quick too. How do I make my background to repeat itself throughout the page? I have tried css repeat, it does not work for some reason.

```
#main_container{
    background:url(../images/cb.jpg)  top left repeat;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:100px 0 150px 0;
    z-index:9999;   


body{
    background-color:#000;
    color:#fff;
    padding:0 0 0 0;
    margin:0 0 0 0;
    width:100%;
    display:table;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    position:relative;  
}
```

Comment: Add your code here please, dont post links!!!

Comment: It's working for me on Chrome if you mean the Jeans Cloth like background.

Comment: it is working because I have used padding longer than an average page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you see is because your #main-container doesnt fill the full page, you need to extend it for the full height of the page. Why are you using

```
 body { display: table }
```

in your css? I'd remove that since it could confuse some browsers and shouldn't make any sense...

An easy workaround would be to put the background image in the `body` tag instead if that is an option for you?

Otherwise you could always add css to your #main-container:

#main_container {
        position: absolute;
        top: 100px;
        bottom: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
   }

and keep your `body  { position: relative; }`

Comment: but the page sizes change from screen to screen, no? I want it to be fixed

Comment: I would also say that that's the problem... Make a new background image so it can fit the whole screen ( like 3000*2200 ). Or stretch your image.

Comment: really? no, I do not want to use pic background pic

Comment: What didn't? did you take away the display: table and added bg to body?

Comment: My bad, background actually worked now. but everything has moved to left.

Comment: body{
 background:url(../images/cb.jpg)  top left repeat;
 background-color:#000;
 color:#fff;
 padding:0 0 0 0;
 margin:0 0 0 0;
 width:100%;
 overflow-x:hidden;
 position:relative; 
}

Comment: #main_container{
 margin:0 auto;
 padding:100px 0 0 0;
 z-index:9999;

Comment: would you also know why number on that page is showing in blue on ipad?

Comment: Thats a native iOS behaviour, see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html for instance. or http://litmus.com/blog/remove-blue-links-ios

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`background-repeat`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/background-repeat):

```
#main_container{
    ...
    'background-repeat:repeat;'
}
```

It should work on your browser if your not using netscape or smthn like that ^^

Comment: Just a note that w3schools is an unreliable source see http://w3fools.com/, also you shouldn't be using inline styles just to override specificity of the css.

Comment: A better reference could be MDN. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-repeat

Comment: @AlvinWong I usually link MDN, but sitepoint is better for descriptive purposes, rather than general reference

Comment: that still does not go till the bottom :S